# how to add "StartOnMainThread" in info.plist on os x

Tags: install4j

I want to make info.plist file on OX S

I want to add

> StartOnMainThread key in  Java key of dict tag

I have already written "StartOnMainThread" Directory entry.
[image]

It failed.

=================  I wan to make this info.plist file ===============================
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit your the launcher and select "Uses SWT or QT", then StartOnMainThread will be added to the Info.plist file.

If you really need to modify the Info.plist file manually, go to the "Executable options->Mac OS X options" to add a fragment that will be added to the Info.plist file.